# How does a charger know when to stop charging a BAD battery?

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-charging

I have a straight forward question that I was thinking about earlier. So I've read that battery chargers will usually periodically measure voltage and decide based off that when to stop charging the battery. Let's say for a car battery this is 13.8V.

If you had a car battery that was damaged somehow and only able to output 13.6V, what would happen if you connected it to one of these chargers that only stop supplying when it reaches the 13.8V mark?

Comment: That would depend on the type of charger and the type of failure.  It's not quiet clear what sort of failure would lead to the behavior you propose - typically a "bad" rechargeable battery will rise in voltage, but not store much energy and so deplete quite quickly when switched to discharge mode.  Or it simply won't absorb energy from the charger and appear like a nearly open circuit.  But proper charge voltage depends on things like temperature, too...

Comment: you answered your own question .. `chargers that only stop supplying when it reaches the 13.8V mark` ... it would not stop trying to charge the battery

Comment: A shorted cell could cause this ... the other 5 will become overcharged.

Comment: That may explain 'boiling' car batteries ! I've experienced one with an 'intelligent' charger.